# Configuring IBM Tealeaf with website

Tags: analytics, tealeaf

I have just started exploring IBM Tealeaf 9.0.2. Actually I need to evaluate one of our client's website using Tealeaf, but I am unable to understand how to configure Tealeaf in the website.

I have Installed base Tealeaf portal already, but I didn't find anything to add the website in it to save sessions, replay, search etc.

Do I need to paste any code in my website source, or something else?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you want to capture web-page with tealeaf, you have two options:

1. if you have access to web server, then just include tealeaf.js at every page which you want to capture.
2. if you don't have access to web-pages then install fiddler and configure your tealeaf.js file in fiddler, and then start capture.

there are many other thing after these process to see the session in tealeaf portal. please ask freely if required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add code in your website that will enable your website for search. Tealeaf engines stores the request-response pairs as a hit in the database only for those pages, which are allowed to be stored. Or as a matter of fact, whole website.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing visitors interaction on your site you have to include tealeaf javascript file in website pages. Only after that you can see the replay in tealeaf portal .